# how clone select object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the next code:

```
<select type="text" id="cls">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

and i want clone this object i have the next javascript

```
var cls = $( "#cls" ).clone();
```

but when i do

```
'<a>' `+ cls + '</a>'
```

return the next:

```
'<a> [object object] </a>'
```

how i do for returned

```
'<a> <select type="text" id="cls">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
    </select> </a>'
```

Comment: You have to use outerHTML. `'<a>' + cls[0].outerHTML + '</a>'`

Comment: Or `cls.wrap('<a></a>')`.. I'm not sure what you are about to achieve by wrapping `select` element in `<a>`

Comment: You can use cls.html()

Comment: Why are you putting a select element as the child of an anchor?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). What clone returns is a jQuery object, not a plain text string. So, if you want to "work" and modify your cloned object I suggest you to do something similar to this:

**HTML**

```
<select type="text" id="cls">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<a class="target"></a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var clonedObject = $('#cls').clone();

// Do your stuff like
clonedObject.toggleClass('active');

clonedObject.appendTo('.target');
```

If the anchor doesn't exist in document

```
var anchor = $('<a/>', {class: 'target'});
$('#my-target').append(anchor.append(clonedObject));
```